# Remove space after echo

Tags: php, html

is there a way to remove the white space after the echo?

```php
<a href='#placement_link' id='placement_link' class="popup-link">
    <?php echo "Test" ?>
</a>

    <?php echo "," ?>
```

The output is: `Test ,`

I want the output to be `Test,`

Any solution to remove the white space before the comma?

Comment: Please post your actual code. This won't even compile, let alone produce the output you give.

Comment: Do you see the space between `</a>` and your `<?php` that is the space

Comment: @Nick it does produce the result. It's a html space

Comment: @Andreas it's not a HTML space

Comment: @Jona yes it is. It's right there.

Comment: Does your code even work?

Comment: The posted code is completely invalid for multiple reasons so please, post the _actual_ code. If not, we will just spend our time focusing on the wrong things. The biggest issues with the posted code is that you're not closing the "class" attribute, you're also not closing the opening `a`-tag and the string you're echoing is missing the closing quote.

Comment: if you want to remove spaces uses the function str_replace()
$str = str_replace(' ','',$str);

Comment: @Mz1907 - That would remove all spaces in the string. That's not what the OP asks for.

Comment: And most likely the space is not I PHP. As the example shows in question there are spaces in the html

Comment: I'm sorry.. I failed to copy my code : (

Comment: @Jona is it html space you have or not?

Comment: @Eriksson if you understand his question feel free to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
<a href='#p4_link' id='p4_link' class="popup">
    <?= "Test" ?>
</a>
<?= "," ?>
```

Do something like this

```
<a href='#p4_link' id='p4_link' class="popup"><?= "Test" ?></a><?= "," ?>
```

linebreaks in html are wild sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Canbe use this

```
<?php echo trim(LANG['section3_p4']) ?>
<?php echo trim(LANG['section3_p5']) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stay in php and echo the html. That is always a safe way to not have extra spaces included.

```
<?PHP  
echo '<a href=\'#p4_link\' id=\'p4_link\' class="popup-';
echo LANG['section3_p4'];
echo "</a>";
echo LANG['section3_p5'];
?>
```

But isn't there missing a `>` before the closing anchor?

Edit, now what I'm sitting by a computer I can show you what I mean.

[image]

The highlighted area is HTML spaces. But in HTML (unless PRE tag is used) only one space shows up in the browser.
So your indentation of the php tag means you add a space.
I can prove it to you, just add the `<pre>`tag before this snippet and `</pre>` after and you will see four spaces instead of one in your output.

Comment: You could also simply write it all on one line in HTML. Also, I would recommend using `"` for the HTML attributes so you don't need to escape the quotes in the string, which will be less error prone and more readable.

Comment: I just used OPs code. Didn't bother more than not creating a syntax error